# 2016 Spain Math Olympiad final stage, problem 2

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, quadratic-residues

> Given a prime $p$. Prove that there exist $\alpha$ such that $p|\alpha(\alpha-1)+3$, if and only if there exist $\beta$ such that $p|\beta(\beta-1)+25$.

My solution:

Using quadratic residuu we have that $$\alpha=\frac{1\pm \sqrt{-11}}{2}$$ $$\beta=\frac{1\pm \sqrt{-99}}{2}=\frac{1\pm 3\sqrt{-11}}{2}$$
Since $p$ must be an odd prime, $\frac{1}{2}$ has inverse mudulo $p$. Supose that there exists $\alpha$ then $\sqrt{-11}$ exists modulo $p$. Hence $\beta$ also exists. The reciprocal is the same.

Could anyone please check this solution? And does anyone has another solution?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't get this problem. What should be determined to solve it? Do you have to find $p$, or do you have to prove the statement for all $p$, or what?

Comment: @Crostul Sorry I write it now correctly

Comment: @Crostul Now is changed

Comment: Much better. OK, it seems that everything is fine. Both statements are equivalent on saying that $-11$ is a square mod $p$. Good job. Maybe there is some trouble for $p=3$?

Comment: @Crostul yes but it can be show by hand other than this is correct right?

Comment: @zyx this is from this year's it is currently doing it abou 6h ago :)

Comment: @zyx it is the final round, or the national.

Comment: I modified the title to include the information.  To do this for any question, click on the "edit" link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For $p=2$, or any prime where $3=25$, the conditions are identical.

For odd primes,

$x^2 - x = a$ is solvable if and only if $4a+1$ is a perfect square.

The statement is now that $-11$ and $-99$ are both squares or both nonsquares.  For $p \neq 3$ that is clear and for $3$ one can calculate.

So there is some special verification at $p=2$ (where completing the square does not work) and $p=3$ (where multiplication by 9 can change a nonsquare into a square) and the argument using quadratic equations or completing the square handles all other values of $p$.